# Jmeter how to find the difference in two time which is stored in string

Tags: jmeter

I have below values
String CurrentTime1=${__groovy(${__groovy(Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS','${Modified_date_1}').getTime(),)},)}
log.info("Current time1 ----> "+CurrentTime1);
String beforetime=vars.get("beforetime");

log.info(" after time -->"+beforetime);

Result:
Current time1 ----> 1611495406402
after time -->1611495402100

As there are stored in string, i am not able to get the difference between these values. Can you please help.

I need to get the difference between current time and before time which are dynamic values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in Groovy - you need to convert the string to [Long](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html) like:

```
def before = vars.get('beforetime') as long
def current =  vars.get('CurrentTime1') as long

def delta = current - before
def deltaAsString = delta as String
```

If you prefer using JMeter Functions - you can go for [__longSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum)

```
${__longSum(${CurrentTime1},-${beforetime},)}
```

[image]

More information on this and other JMeter Functions: [How to Use JMeter Functions - Part III](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii)

But don't mix both approaches like inlining JMeter functions in Groovy code, as per [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) documentation:

> When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement. Instead use script parameters.

Comment: I am getting -Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'null' to class 'long'. Try 'java.lang.Long' instead for Groovy

Comment: It means that either `beforetime` or `CurrentTime1` variable is not defined (or both), check whether they have anticipated values using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/), if you don't see them - revisit the place where you declare/create these variables.